# equivalent of *args in R and summing up a function to itself

Tags: r, function

Say I have a binomial.coeff function defined as:

```
combn <- function(n,r) {
  factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))
}

binomial.coeff <- function(n,x,p) {
  combn(n,x)*p^x*(1-p)^(n-x)
}
```

I would like to call the function `binomial.coeff` for different values of `x` and sum the calls to produce the result. I'm not sure if `R` takes many positional arguments like this:

```
binomial.coeff <- function(n,...,p) {
    combn(n,...)*p^...*(1-p)^(n-...)
}
```

My final goal is say `x` takes values `[3,2]` then I would like to have the function being summed on `3 and 2`

```
binomial.coeff <- function(n,x,p) {
  combn(n,3)*p^3*(1-p)^(n-3)+combn(n,2)*p^2*(1-p)^(n-2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using functions that are themselves vectorized, you can pass in a vector for `x` with

```
binomial.coeff(3,2:3,.25)
# [1] 0.140625 0.015625
```

and sum that with

```
sum(binomial.coeff(3,2:3,.25))
# [1] 0.15625
```

More generally, if you want to call it multiple times with different parameter values, in R you'd use something like `sapply`. For example

```
sapply(2:3, function(x) binomial.coeff(3, x, .25))
# [1] 0.140625 0.015625
sum(sapply(2:3, function(x) binomial.coeff(3, x, .25)))
# [1] 0.15625
```

But the code you've written seems to be the pmf for the binomial distribution. There is a built in function for that `dbinom` You could do the same thing with

```
dbinom(2:3, 3, .25)
# [1] 0.140625 0.015625
sum(dbinom(2:3, 3, .25))
# [1] 0.15625
```

in one call because `dbinom` is vectorized over the `x` argument. Also this version would be more efficient.

Comment: amazing, thanks. but is there an equivalent `*args` of Python in R i.e. can I pass an unspecified number of arguments to a function ?

Comment: If you use `...` you can capture all those values with `args<- c(...)` or `args <- list(...)` but you can't as easily inject those values into new function calls with base R. Basically you'd have to use `do.call()` to build a function call. The `rlang` package used by `tidyverse` has options for expanding parameters with `!!!` but it's hard to use that feature in a non-tidy/rlang context.